startup command for azure bot
I am trying to create an azure bot using Python azure sdk framework and deploy on azure app service/ azure bot. The bot works well on my local with emulator (windows laptop). But once I deploy (its a linux environment) it does not work in the test web chat option in azure.
The startup command I have tried are
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --timeout 600 app:app
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --worker-class aiohttp.GunicornWebWorker --timeout 600 app:app
but both dont work.

Try this command python3 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:app.

Add init_func() in the app.py with below code:
def init_func(argv):
    APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
    APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
    return APP
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = init_func(None)

    try:
        web.run_app(APP, host="0.0.0.0", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error

Modified app.py full code:
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License.

import sys
import traceback
from datetime import datetime

from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web import Request, Response, json_response
from botbuilder.core import (BotFrameworkAdapter, BotFrameworkAdapterSettings,
                             TurnContext)
from botbuilder.core.integration import aiohttp_error_middleware
from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ActivityTypes

from bot import MyBot
from config import DefaultConfig

CONFIG = DefaultConfig()

# Create adapter.
# See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about how bots work.

SETTINGS = BotFrameworkAdapterSettings(CONFIG.APP_ID, CONFIG.APP_PASSWORD)
ADAPTER = BotFrameworkAdapter(SETTINGS)


# Catch-all for errors.
async def on_error(context: TurnContext, error: Exception):
    # This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    # NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    #       application insights.
    print(f"\n [on_turn_error] unhandled error: {error}", file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exc()

    # Send a message to the user
    await context.send_activity("The bot encountered an error or bug.")
    await context.send_activity(
        "To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code."
    )
    # Send a trace activity if we're talking to the Bot Framework Emulator
    if context.activity.channel_id == "emulator":
        # Create a trace activity that contains the error object
        trace_activity = Activity(
            label="TurnError",
            name="on_turn_error Trace",
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            type=ActivityTypes.trace,
            value=f"{error}",
            value_type="https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
        )
        # Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
        await context.send_activity(trace_activity)


ADAPTER.on_turn_error = on_error

# Create the Bot
BOT = MyBot()


# Listen for incoming requests on /api/messages
async def messages(req: Request) -> Response:
    # Main bot message handler.
    if "application/json" in req.headers["Content-Type"]:
        body = await req.json()
    else:
        return Response(status=415)

    activity = Activity().deserialize(body)
    auth_header = req.headers["Authorization"] if "Authorization" in req.headers else ""

    response = await ADAPTER.process_activity(activity, auth_header, BOT.on_turn)
    if response:
        return json_response(data=response.body, status=response.status)
    return Response(status=201)


def init_func(argv):
    APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
    APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
    return APP
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = init_func(None)

    try:
        web.run_app(APP, host="0.0.0.0", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error


Use the below startup command in the Web App=>Configuration=>General Settings=>StartupCommand:

python3 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func



Update the values of Microsoft App ID and Microsoft Password (copy from Azure Bot=>Configuration) in the config.py:

import os

class DefaultConfig:
    """ Bot Configuration """

    PORT = 3978
    APP_ID = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppId", "1238ceab-47a6-XXXX23c8")
    APP_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppPassword", "xP78Q~u5D3hmLQXXXXXXXRbTw")


Update the Web Application's URL https://appname.azurewebsites.net appending /api/messages to it in the Azure Bot's configuration=>Messaging Endpoint:


Test the Azure Bot web chat:

